# how to get public ip address of my localhost system

Tags: php

I am connected to a lan.. I can access internet. using the browser I can find my public ip using the search "what is my ip".

I want to get the public ip using php

I am running the script in my `localhost` wamp server..

I tried:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` both give me `localhost ip ::1
```

Is there any networking functions that can give me my public ip address?

is there any way without using any external service? because if I use an external service, it may not available in the future.

Comment: Regarding your edit (without using any external service), no, you cannot.

Comment: @roberto06 but depending on external service may break my code in the future..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this please:

```
$externalContent = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
preg_match('/Current IP Address: \[?([:.0-9a-fA-F]+)\]?/', $externalContent, $m);
$externalIp = $m[1];
```

Or use httpbin.org/ip as Priyesh Kumar suggests

Comment: is there any way without using any external service?

Comment: Both links do not use cookies.

Answer (score 6):

You can use API to get public IP address from localhost.

https://www.ipify.org/

```
<?php
    $ip = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org');
    echo "My public IP address is: " . $ip;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this too and check with print_r

```
$ip= isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score -1):

I Think you should use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the IP address of the router

Answer (score -1):

Try this as it is tested on **local machine(localhost)**

$ip = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org'); echo $ip;